# Django - Checking database for session variable

Tags: django, session, authentication

Somewhat new Djangoer here. A (hopefully) quick question.

Is it possible to check is another user is active at the moment? My site does not have logins in the traditional sense; there is no authentication. Users are assigned a randomly generated username, stored in their session whilst on the website, and can interact with the website under that username. I would like other users to be able to view these interactions and check if the user who made them is still active or is offline (their session has ended).

On another related note, the different pages have admins who are saved as IP addresses. Is it possible to check if a particular IP is online?

Comment: You can filter session data in the RDB by expire_date to get the latest active user

Answer (score 0):

This website has a really handy solution that worked with a little modification:

https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/django-tutorial-get-list-of-current-users/

```
def get_current_users():
    active_sessions = Session.objects.filter(expire_date__gte=timezone.now())
    user_id_list = []
    for session in active_sessions:
        data = session.get_decoded()
        user_id_list.append(data.get('_auth_user_id', None))
    # Query all logged in users based on id list
    return User.objects.filter(id__in=user_id_list)
```